# ask for easy to use Silverlight player sample

Tags: silverlight, video, multimedia

My purpose is simple, to find a sample which is just enough for my usage other than reading a long page sample. :-)

My requirement is very simple, just embed a Silverlight player into web browser to play some specific videos, the videos are hosted on an IIS server, some are wmv format and some others are flash format.

Any quick to reference samples? :-)

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 0):

Download Expression Encoder and grab the various templates you wnat from there (it also has the ability to auto-publish to silverlight.live.com for streaming, so we can handle the burden of video hosting as well - for free! :)

Under the Output tab, you'll have a pick from a bunch of templates there (pick which one takes your fancy, and grab that code and cut & paste it into your said page)

**Scott Barnes / Rich Platforms Product Manager / Microsoft.**